# Not showing the total number of size in each bar in its graph in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, axes

I have a problem about showing the numbers above each bar in its graph.

Here is my dafaframe which is shown below.

```
ID  SEX count
6   Secret Identity Male Characters 1751
3   Public Identity Male Characters 1662
1   Public Identity Female Characters   765
4   Secret Identity Female Characters   625
2   Public Identity Genderless Characters   11
0   Identity Unknown    Male Characters 9
5   Secret Identity Genderless Characters   5
```

Here is my code function which is shown below.

```
def show_values_on_bars(axs, h_v="v", space= 0.4):
    
    def _show_on_single_plot(ax):
        if h_v == "v":
            for p in ax.patches:
                _x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2
                _y = p.get_y() + p.get_height()
                value = int(p.get_height())
                ax.text(_x, _y, value, ha="center", fontsize=18) 
        elif h_v == "h":
            for p in ax.patches:
                _x = p.get_x() + p.get_width()
                _y = p.get_y() + p.get_height() - float(space)                
                value = int(p.get_width())
                ax.text(_x, _y, value, ha="left", fontsize=18)

    if isinstance(axs, np.ndarray):
        for idx, ax in np.ndenumerate(axs):
            _show_on_single_plot(ax)
    else:
        _show_on_single_plot(axs)
```

When I run this code snippets defined below, I got an error message which is shown below.

```
graph_3 = sns.barplot(data = dc_df, 
            x = "ID" , 
            y = "count", ax=a[1,0], hue='SEX')

show_values_on_bars(graph_3, "v", 0.3)
```

The error : `value = int(p.get_height()) -> ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly check it and assign value to 0 is `p.get_height()` is NaN.

```py
import numpy as np

def show_values_on_bars(axs, h_v="v", space= 0.4):
    
    def _show_on_single_plot(ax):
        if h_v == "v":
            for p in ax.patches:

                value = 0
                if not np.isnan(p.get_height()):
                    value = int(p.get_height())

                _x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2
                _y = p.get_y() + value

                ax.text(_x, _y, value, ha="center", fontsize=18)
```

Comment: I got a graph thanks to your help but I got some red warning `posx and posy should be finite values`. How can remove them?

Comment: You could put the complete block until `ax.text()` inside the `if not np.isnan(p.get_height()):`, effectively skipping the patches that have a NaN height or width.